# Get children count via HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I have a one-to-many mapping between a parent entity and child entities. Now I need to find the number of children associated with each parent for a list of parents. I am trying to do this with HQL but I am not sure how I can get the list of parents in there. Also, I don't know how I can return the entity itself and not just its ID. My current HQL query is:

```
select new map(parent.id as parentId, count(*) as childCount) 
from Parent parent left join parent.children children
group by parent.id
```

but this only returns the ID and does not filter on specific parents.

**EDIT**
Based on Pascal's answer I have modified the query to

```
select new map(parent as parent, count(elements(parent.children)) as childCount) 
from Parent parent
group by parent
```

That does work, but is prohibitively slow: 30 seconds instead of 400 ms on the same database.

Comment: Indeed, that's horribly slow. Hardly acceptable actually...

Comment: Indexes may (emphasis on may) help with the speed, but the other option is to break out the hql query into parts if you can - I have found that to sometimes help.  Or you could do seperate queries for each parent element, and create the map yourself.  A good database profiler will likely help with the exploration.

Comment: The solution I chose in the end is to first retrieve all parents from the database, then run the query which gives me parent IDs and counts and then merge the two in Java. I have to get all the parents anyway, and merging that list with the child count takes less than one second, which is ok in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that but what about this:

```
select new map(parent.id, count(elements(parent.children)))
from Parent parent group by parent.id
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I get an SQL-Exception when doing that because the generated SQL groups by parent.id but selects lots of other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I was looking for the number of children for a particular parent and your posts got me heading in the right direction.

In case anyone else needs to find the number of children for a particular parent, you could use something like this:

```
Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(elements(parent.children)) from Parent parent where name = :name");
query.setString("name", parentName);
System.out.println("count = " + query.uniqueResult());
```